# Problem rendering gnome ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome

I'm having problems with gnome-shell 45.2 in Ubuntu 23.10

After some update (not really know what exactly) gnome is rendering strange, with no icons, displaced, and missing text.

[image: gnome settings with problems]

I also checked the `journalctl` and `dmesg`, and there are no gnome errors.
This also happened in files, extension manager (GTK apps)

Any help, please?

Comment: Create a new user account. Does the problem persist when you login to the new account?

Comment: I crated a new user, but same result. It appears to other problem, due to in GDM the problem also happend.

Comment: "kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell)" to restart

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today. In my case, it was related to the graphic cards. My graphic card is the `amdgpu`, I was using from the oibaf repository. After some time trying to fix it, only removing the drivers from PPA (using ppa purge) and reinstalling the graphics cards solved this issue.

Comment: That was the problem, i updated packages from oibaf ppa and started working well.